# Android: Launching an activity from my ForgroundService's Task, causes the task to block :(

Tags: android, android-intent, service, foreground-service

I have a task (launched from my Foreground Service) that launches an activity like so:
(note this is c#/xamarin)

```
new Android.OS.Handler( Looper.MainLooper ).Post( new Java.Lang.Runnable( ( ) =>
{
    Intent i = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage( appname );

    i.AddFlags( (ActivityFlags) 524288 ); // FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

    StartActivity( i );
}));
```

Sadly this didnt make any difference to just calling the above synchronously.

Once I exit the launched Activity the task starts rolling again.

How can I launch the activity so that it doesnt block my task when the new Activity is in the foreground?

Note I am not having issues launching the app (I appreciate it wont work on Android 10+).

I have the same problem if I run the service as background service and other thread incarnations are also suspended.

Interestingly the thread/task doesnt get suspended till the new Activity is completely initialised. The thread still runs for about 5 seconds following the StartActivity() call.

Is it the launch of the new activity or the fact that the Actvity that spawned the Service is no longer at the front, that causes the thread to suspend? That said, the thread keeps running if that Activity is 'minimised'.

An help would be appreciated as I've invested a lot of time in the hardware for this project - this should have been the easy bit!?

If my question is not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that my dev device (huawei p smart/EMUI phone) is just very stingy on background processing. I tried disabling battery saving, ensured I had standard 20 background process limit. I tried Alarms/Braodcast receiver, and other ways to poke my process. Sometimes it would work for a while, but would always grind to a halt. Good news is the target device is fine. The thread ticks away happily, no matter what the device is doing. I would still like to know if it's possible to force background processing (while other apps running), if anyone has any comments.